# how to use target specific variable in gnu make

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

i have a makefile like:

```
file1 = "path/to/some/file"
header="col1;col2;col3"

$(file1):
      some steps to create the file
call_perl_script:$(file1)
      ${perl} script.pl in=header
```

The header is currently hardcoded and it is also there in generated file1. I need to fetch the header from file1. Somehow i have changed it like

```
file1 = "path/to/some/file"

$(file1):
      some steps to create the file
      $(eval header="$(shell $(sed) -n "/^col1;col2;col3/Ip" $(file1))")
call_perl_script:$(file1)
      ${perl} script.pl in=$(header)
```

It works fine but want to know if it is correct way to work with target specific variable. The header does not get its value passed until used with eval.
Also if I print $(header) in the call_perl_script target it prints correctly but if i use "if" condition to check if variable is empty and set default value, then it does not work. It sets the value of header in "if" block irrespective of the the value in header from "sed" output.

```
call_perl_script:$(file1)
${echo} $(header)
ifeq "$(header)" ""
      $(eval header="col1;col2;col3")
endif
      ${perl} script.pl in=$(header)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think target-specific variables will help you here, because they’re usually static things. For example, if you need to silence one type of warning for one specific C file, you can add a rule like `foo.o: CFLAGS+=-Whatever`.

The problem you’re running into is that `$(eval header=...)` is only executed when `$(file1)` is made. If it already exists, then the target won’t get rebuilt, and `header` won’t get set.

A more natural way of doing this in a Makefile would be to save the header to a separate file. That way, it will automatically get regenerated whenever `$(file)` changes:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

file = foo.txt

call_perl_script: $(file) $(file).header
        echo perl script.pl in="$(shell cat $(file).header)"

$(file):
        echo "col1;col2;col3;$$(head -c1 /dev/random)" > $(file)

%.header: %
        sed -n '/^col1;col2;col3/p' $< > $@

clean::
        rm -f $(file)
        rm -f *.header
```

which results in:

```
echo "col1;col2;col3;$(head -c1 /dev/random)" > foo.txt
sed -n '/^col1;col2;col3/p' foo.txt > foo.txt.header
perl script.pl in="col1;col2;col3;?"
```

However this is still a bit of a kludge, so for long-term maintainability, you may want to consider updating `script.pl` to parse out the header itself.